# Bash shell script with $1 as variable with wildcards

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a basic bash script that currently looks for input of a specified file as a variable and if it is blank, processes the whole directory.

if i specify a file on execution such as `script.sh file1.txt` then it processes that file.

What I want and cannot figure out, is how to specify multiple files with wildcards. For example:

```
script.sh file*.txt
```

I guess it needs some simple loop, but I could not find any examples that matched this scenario.

When I try to do a loop, it only processes the first match.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "no argument supplied, pulling all file from tick_tock"

    for i in /var/tank/tick_tock/*.txt; do
        cp "$i" /var/tank/awaiting/
    done
fi
echo "you supplied $1"
cp "$1" /var/tank/awaiting/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is that the wildcard pattern expands to *multiple* arguments, not just to a single argument at `$1`. The others are in `$2`, `$3`, etc. You can't index into those with standard shell features, but usually you don't need to: you can access the list of arguments to the script with `"$@"`. So:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "no arguments"
else
    echo "$# arguments:"
    for x in "$@"; do
        echo " $x"     # or do whatever with $x
    done
fi
```

Something like `cp -- "$@" /var/tank/awaiting/` would in turn call `cp` with the files the script got as arguments. The `--` there prevents any following arguments from being taken as options to `cp`.

Answer (score 2):

If you invoke a script with:

```
$ script.sh file*.txt
```

and if there are matches, then the shell will expand that glob to the list of files matches.  Assume, for instance, that you have `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `file3.txt`, then the above command is equivalent to:

```
$ script.sh file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

The order may differ, but that's not important here.

One option do handling the files in that case is a loop like:

```bsh
while [[ $# -ne 0 ]]; do
    # process ${1}
    shift
done
```

The `shift` will discard the old `${1}` and *shift* the remaining parameters "left" by one (2 becomes 1, 3 becomes 2, etc).  The `shift` also updates `$#`.

For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while [[ $# -ne 0 ]]; do
    echo ${1}
    shift
done
```

If I run that script, I see:

```
$ ./script.sh a b c
a
b
c
$
```

Comment: Globs are supposed to be expanded in the locale sort order, so `file[123].txt` should come in that order. Not that you'd usually need to care or rely on that, but it can be useful with e.g. file names containing timestamps.